# Sum Dice sample results and place them into a table

Tags: r

I am running a simulation on rolling dice
I stored on die roll

```
dieRolls <- sample(1:6,5000, replace = TRUE)
```

In order to simulate two dice being rolled we utilize the replicate function to simulate rolling two dice

```
replicate(2,dieRolls)
TwoRolledDiceSample <- replicate(2,dieRolls)
```

Now I need to create a table of the sums of the two dice and utilizing

```
table(TwoRolledDiceSample)
```

Only returns the number of time a 1:6 was rolled. Any help will be greatly appreciated as I am a first time learner

Comment: table(TwoRolledDiceSample[,1]+TwoRolledDiceSample[,2])

Comment: I am curious if there is a particular reason why only even dice rolls are coming out. There is no option for 3, 5, 7 basically all the odds any ideas?

Comment: Ahhh use replicate(2, sample(1:6,5000, replace = TRUE)) you was adding the same item previously

Comment: Thank you so much to everyone it worked beautifully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you only roll once and then copy that results, that is not simulating 2 dice.

try:

```
dieRolls <- replicate(2,sample(1:6,5000, replace = TRUE))
TwoRolledDiceSample <- as.data.frame(dieRolls)
TwoRolledDiceSample$sum = TwoRolledDiceSample$V1 + TwoRolledDiceSample$V2
```

and then

```
table(TwoRolledDiceSample$sum )
```

Comment: A bit more efficient might be `table(rowSums(dieRolls))`

Comment: I am sure there are many ways to make all this code much more efficient, but this is relatively easy to follow.